# How to avoid having my GameManager class be friend with most stuff?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a game for a video game course (which unfortunately taught nothing), and I'm having trouble designing the interactions between the game entities and the class that actually runs the game.

My problem reduces pretty much to this: assuming an entity has a position, it shouldn't be able to modify it directly (instead having to wait for the game manager to run a game step), but it should be able to access it, to run AI checks and so on.

My solution would be to create a `Position` class that is friend with `GameManager`, and to create an entity class like this

```
class Entity {
    public:
        Position & getPosition() { return pos_; }
    private:
        Position pos_;
};
```

So the manager would be able to modify the entities' positions but other classes would only be able to observe. However this reasoning would hold for lots and lots of other properties, and since the entity class is actually derived into a series of subclasses, which have more and more properties, I would have to put the `friend` attribute almost everywhere.

What would be a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you're making it a little too complicated. An Entity, outside of the context of your game, has a position which can be requested or modified, thus Entity should provide a getter and setter for the position. It is not the responsibility of Entity to ensure that its position setter is called at appropriate times

Comment: @bengoesboom So it would be simply the responsibility of whoever was keeping the Entity instance to return a non-const reference to it only to the Manager class? If so, how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of identifying certain classes as friend and certain others as non-friend is not a good idea, for many reasons. What this means is that,

**How this class is being used is also a concern of this class.**

But this is not its concern at all. This class, whatever class is under consideration, should be designed to do its own responsibility.

Now, with your case, first of all you should decide on where **the action/behaviour of changing position** belongs to; does it belong to Entity, Entity Manager, or something else. For example, which of these two cases make more sense:

1. Entity changes its position from x1 to x2.
2. Entity Manager changes to position of Entity from x1 to x2.

Suppose you decided that this behaviour really belongs to Entity, rather than Entity manager (case 1). In that case, as is pointed out in the comments by @bengoesboom, it should provide a setter that users of the class can use to change its position.

Now, if you think that this class might be used in ways that is not desired, then you should enforce constraints and business rules within this class. For example (just a simple example), if you want to allow only certain range of values in an operation. You check the input, if it is not in the range, then you throw an exception.

Once, you have properly taken care of rules and constraints, then you don't care about who will use this class.

Comment: My concern is that in this way one would be encouraged to code in a way that breaks the rules of the game. Suppose I extend `Entity` and I create an `Animal` class that wants to go to food. One would think that doing `setPosition(gameManager.getFoodPosition())` could be an acceptable solution, while in reality it is not.

Comment: It is hard to comment any further without having more information about the context.